# Shuffle an existing column multiple times with no repeats on any row

Tags: vba, multiple-columns, shuffle

I am using VBA

I have a column of integers in an array

I run the array thru a randomizer module and copy that to a second column

I run the array thru a randomizer module and copy that to a third column

I run the array thru a randomizer module and copy that to a fourth column

The issue I can't seem to over come is duplicates on the same row

IE:

```
    2   13   27   14
    27  27   13   5
    14  5    2    13
    13  2    14   27
    5   14   5    2
```

*columns are much longer

I have searched the web but everyone is focused on creating random numbers without duplicate. I have found shuffling but once again it seems to be one dimensional.

```
'// get a random number from 1 to the last row of column 25
For N1 = 1 To LastRow
Again:
    Randomize Timer
    RNum = Int(Rnd * (LastRow - 1 + 1) + 1)


'// this is where the values in "NArray" get shuffled around
    Temp = NArray(N1)
    NArray(N1) = NArray(RNum)
    NArray(RNum) = Temp

    ws5.Cells(N1, Lp) = NArray(N1)

'// this looks for duplicate numbers in the row
    Select Case Lp
        Case 26:    a = ws5.Cells(N1, Lp).Value + 0
                b = ws5.Cells(N1, Lp - 1).Value + 0
                If a = b Then
                    GoTo Again
                End If
        Case 27:    a = ws5.Cells(N1, Lp).Value + 0
                b = ws5.Cells(N1, Lp - 2).Value + 0
                c = ws5.Cells(N1, Lp - 1).Value + 0
                If a = b Then
                    GoTo Again
                ElseIf a = c Then
                    GoTo Again
                End If
```

...
    '// the shuffled array is inserted into the cells of column 26
    For N1 = 1 To LastRow
        ws5.Cells(N1, Lp) = NArray(N1)
    Next N1
    Next Lp

no errors with the exception that when comparing cell values in the row going from column to column it misses duplicate values such as row 2 column 3 may contain "14" and row 2 column 4 contains "14" it doesn't loop back and get another value for column 4

Comment: Have you tried storing the random numbers into dictionaries and check them while randomize runs? So if you get a number wich index (row) is the same, try another one.

Comment: as you can see from my code that I am not an excel guru, this being said I hadn't heard about dictionaries before but I just googled it and it may work, just have to figure out the verbiage.

Comment: look up for "vba for smarties dictionaries" I learned there how to use them

Comment: Are the values in the initial array column UNIQUE?  Is one goal to have all COMBIINATIONS and PERMUTATIONS of these numbers, or just have 4 values?  Shuffle the first column, then for each row shuffle the first column into a work area and strike out the value that was in the first column, taking the first  3 remaining values.

Comment: Yes the values in the initial array column are Unique. No I don't want all permutations, I'm trying to get unique values in each row that is created by shuffling the original array into the following columns